# Problems ordering sqlite by a column with accented characters (Á)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database, and i need to order by a column that haves some words starting by a accented character. These items are being ordered wrong, they are appearing on the end of the results:

Antonio
Bonzo
Zeto
Ángela

How can i order correctly when the sqlite database haves accents in that column?

thanks

Comment: Can You please share your query?

Comment: Select * from users Order By name

Comment: Try something like `... ORDER BY <field> COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Either

```
... ORDER BY column COLLATE UNICODE
```

or

```
... ORDER BY column COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

[Reference:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

> In addition to SQLite's default `BINARY` collator, Android supplies two more, `LOCALIZED`, which changes with the system's current locale, and `UNICODE`, which is the Unicode Collation Algorithm and not tailored to the current locale.

Example:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE foo(a TEXT);");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo VALUES('Antonio'),('Bonzo'),('Zeto'),('Ángela');");

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY a COLLATE UNICODE", null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
   Log.d("foo", c.getString(0));
}
```

Output:

```
Ángela
Antonio
Bonzo
Zeto
```

Comment: I'm getting `no such collation sequence: UNICODE: SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY a COLLATE UNICODE` when I run your `sql` code. Can you point me out what is wrong?

Comment: @dwnz It's the Android sqlite wrapper that installs the `UNICODE` collation sequence. If you're running your SQL elsewhere, you'll have to install the collation sequence yourself, and that's beyond the scope of these comments.

Comment: Ha! Works a treat. UNICODE gave me wrong result (Ł), but LOCALIZED was OK (polish lang)

Answer (score 1):

To support accented characters at database you can use the `Normalizer` class to store the text properly:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

...

// Code to store the normalized data
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(COLUMN_NAME, Normalizer.normalize(name, Normalizer.Form.NFD));

...

// Code to read the normalized data
int indexName = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)
String name = Normalizer.normalize(cursor.getString(indexName), Normalizer.Form.NFC));
```

Storing the data in this way, the SQLite statemants `ASC` and `DESC` works properly with accented characters.