# Android SQLite not Sorting

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Do you know what's wrong about my try of sorting the SQLite results?

Here it's how I do on Java (Android):

```
return database.query("tools", new String[] {"_id","title"}, null, null, null, null, "title Asc");
```

Believe, I already tried this:

```
SELECT _id, title FROM tools ORDER BY title ASC
```

But in both ways, the SQL result is sort by the field **_id** ASC!

Don't know what to do anymore.

Thanks

**[[EDIT]]**

I looked at my results and I guess what's going on.

```
_id          title
 1            test
 2            Ábc
 3            Abcd
```

**title has special characteres**

Comment: Your SQL query should be returning the data ordered by `title`.  Something else would seem to be the problem.

Comment: Why do you think the result is wrong? How do you look at the results?

Comment: @CL. the result is sorting by _id (_id is a incremental field). For example, the result is like this:
1 Test
2 Abc

Where 1, 2 are the _id and Test, Abc the title.

Comment: @GordonLinoff unfortunately the result isn't sorting well, I do a while Log(result) and it's sorting by _id :(

Comment: Show the code that runs the query and logs the result.

Comment: @CL., editted the question. I got what could be the problem, the accents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I got the error.**
My title field has accents.

Problem described here:
[Problems ordering sqlite by a column with accented characters (Á)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906086/problems-ordering-sqlite-by-a-column-with-accented-characters-%C3%81)

Before:

```
SELECT _id, title FROM tools ORDER BY title ASC
```

After:

```
SELECT _id, title FROM tools ORDER BY title COLLATE UNICODE ASC
```

Note that "**COLLATE UNICODE**" ignores the current locale.
The structure must be:

Order By **COLUMN** *COLLATE UNICODE* [ASC/DESC]

Reference: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: @evanwong what essential parts do you have in mind? Does the query not count?

Comment: Now it is better. By the way, I didn't vote you down.