# Saving and retrieving accented characters to mysql database

Tags: android, database, utf-8, android-sqlite

I'm having some trouble saving a string with an accent to my database and retrieving it.

This is my function that saves a new location to the database. It gets 'myId' and 'location' and inserts them. The println there shows the item as I expect, with the accent. The example I'm using is Mazzarrà.

```
public long createLocationRecord(String location, int myId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_OWMID, myId);
    values.put(KEY_NAME, location);
    System.out.println("newItem in DB = "+location);

    long callSQL = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_LOCATION, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    if(callSQL==-1)
        db.update(TABLE_LOCATION, values, KEY_OWMID + '=' + owmId, null);
    return callSQL;
}
```

This is my function to retrieve all location items. The println here prints out Mezzarra, without the accented à. Am I missing something? Do I need to make a change to my database? It's just a regular Android SQLite DB that I'm opening via [SQLiteBrowser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/files/sqlitebrowser/).

```
public ArrayList<String> getLocationList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * "
            + "FROM " + TABLE_LOCATION
            + " ORDER BY _id ASC";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            System.out.println("newItem GETTING FROM DB = "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
            list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return list;
}
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Have you checked this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906086/problems-ordering-sqlite-by-a-column-with-accented-characters-%C3%81 ?

Comment: The comments in there show a good example of how I think you can remove accented characters from a strong by noramlising it. I'm aiming to keep them. Everything I've seen so far says that a standard SQLite DB should be able to hold and retrieve them like I'm trying to do.